# How to link libproxy-dev to existing cmake project(C++)?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, ubuntu-18.04

I am not expert of C++ coding. Got one task where I have to use "libproxy-dev" to detect the proxy automatically.

1. installed  "libproxy-dev" in my ubuntu 18 system: 
   **sudo apt-get install libproxy-dev**
2. imported proxy.h  : **#include**
3. Tried to created object of pxProxyFactory 
   **pxProxyFactory *pf = px_proxy_factory_new();**

when tried to build got an error 
 **undefined reference to `px_proxy_factory_new'**

My question: Am I doing mistake on how we link libproxy to cmake project? Do I have to add/change my CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: These links may help: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html , https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: "Do I have to add/change my CMakeLists.txt?" - It is hard to say what is wrong with your `CMakeLists.txt` without viewing it...

Comment: Yes but generally what kind of change are required there?
Lets say if we have new project and only thing we want to do is to create above mentioned object in this new project. How should our CMakeLists.txt may look like?

Comment: You need to **link** with a library which you use. In CMake this is performed by [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html) command. Almost any CMake tutorial describes how to link. Note, that `libproxy-dev` is a **package** name, not a library. The library name is `libproxy`, and this should definitely be noted in the guide about using this library.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

You miss to add the correct depdendency to your project. I assume you have to add some sort of command like this one into your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(your_target_name proxy)
```

---

**Long answer**

I created a `main.cpp` with this content

```
#include <iostream>
#include <proxy.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl;

    pxProxyFactory *px = px_proxy_factory_new();

    return 0;
}
```

Then I created a `CMakeLists.txt` with this content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(proxy_ex1)

set(MY_SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MY_SOURCES})
```

When now running `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" . && make`, I get the same error message like you: `main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to 'px_proxy_factory_new'`

When now adding the `target_link_libraries` at the end, I can compile my small program:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(proxy_ex1)

set(MY_SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MY_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} proxy)
```

Now I can compile my program with `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" . && make`